# Faster way to remove punctuations and special characters in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm using this below code to remove special characters and punctuations from a column in pandas dataframe. But this method of using regex.sub is not time efficient. Is there other options I could try to have better time efficiency and remove punctuations and special characters? Or the way I'm removing special characters and parsing it back to the column, pandas dataframe is causing me major computation burn?

```
for n, string in data['text'].iteritems():
   data['text'] = re.sub('([{string.punctuation}“”¨«»®´·º½¾¿¡§£₤‘’])','', string)
```

Comment: Why don't you fix your data upstream, ie before you put it into your data frame?

Comment: If you're trying to remove all characters that are not alphanumeric you can just use `re.sub('[\W_]', '', string)`

Comment: what is `data`? Whatever you are doing here doesn't make much sense, you are just overwriting whatever `data['text']` is

Comment: data is the pandas dataframe, same dataframe from where I'm trying to remove special characters. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: anyway, I suspect the *fastest* way will involve `train_data.comment_text.str.translate`

Comment: @MooingRawr I couldn't understand. Can you please elaborate/explain a bit more?

Comment: But your code simply creates a column in `data['text']` filled with a single string, and will end up wiht the last one form your loop....

Comment: @RajeshThevar My comment was basically asking you why are you storing texts that you need to fix? Why not fix the text before you store it into your dataframe.

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for the suggestion. I understand having separate characters inside regex is a cause for a drop in efficiency. I gave it a try now, even then it seems to take a lot of time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OH. I was trying to clean the string of every row and parse it back to the same row location.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, I used map(lambda function) to parse back (replaced) strings with no punctuation back to the column, same row in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to keep only alphanumeric. Consider this dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':['#^#346fetvx@!.,;:', 'fhfgd54@!#><?']})

    Text
0   #^#346fetvx@!.,;:
1   fhfgd54@!#><?
```

You can use

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.extract('(\w+)', expand = False)

    Text
0   346fetvx
1   fhfgd54
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Adding a sub comment which I utilized as well. In the for loop, I used testing_['comment_text'] = testing_['comment_text'].map(lambda value: re.sub('[\W_]',' ',value))

Comment: Glad that it worked. I am not quite clear on the purpose of the loop though

Comment: My thought process was just to have the dataframe column with cleaned up string, removed punctuation and special characters. Overwriting at the same rows with same data but clean string. Looking back now, this idea is a major performance issue.

Comment: Yes, and extracting alpha-numeric values using \w+ is doing just that. If you want to use replace, you can try df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('\W+', '') to the same effect

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex and lambda function:

```
import re
data['PROD_NAME'] = data['PROD_NAME'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', x))
```

This would remove all characters except alphabets and digits.